# Python Multiprocessing: How to find out CPU and Memory used by a child process

Tags: python, memory, cpu-usage, pid, multiprocess

I have a code that will spawn 2 child process:

```
P1 = Process(target=worker, args=(), name="p1")
P1.start()
P1_pid = P1.pid

P2 = Process(target=<a function that will monitor the CPU and Memory used by P1>, args=(P1_pid), name="P2")
P2.start()
```

Basically I need to find a way to create the second child process in a way that the target worker of P2 takes the pid of the child process P1 and gets the CPU and memory that the child process P1 is taking. I need to do this without the use of `psutil`.

Does multiprocessing module come with something like this in-built? I looked for it, but couldn't find it.

I also tried the below, where the below is the logic in the worker task of P2:

```
cmd = "ps -p <P1_pid> -o %cpu,%mem"
MyOut = subprocess.Popen([cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True )
stdout, stderr = MyOut.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

The above prints the below:

```
b' %CPU %MEM\n'
```

Which seemed to make no sense, because if I run the command `ps -p ..` on the normal unix shell then it shows a 0.1 memory usage.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it's ok to get information *post hoc*, you could probably use `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)`.

Comment: ***`b' %CPU %MEM\n'`***: You got no result as the given `-p <pid>` does not exist.
I get `b'%CPU %MEM\n 0.0 0.2\n'` on Python 3.6. Please explain, why do you not want to use `psutil`?

Comment: @stovfl - psutil has some C dependencies, due to which I can't use it. In my case the pid I was looking for was up and running. So i'm not sure why it was empty. I will recheck it.

Comment: @stovfl - So does that mean that psutil has some compilation dependencies?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the [doc](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#id1) *"On UNIX this requires a C compiler (e.g. gcc) installed."* and [used `*.c/*.h` files](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/tree/master/psutil). But why did that bother you?

Comment: @stovfl - It's a limitation that has been provided to me that I can use libraries that are easily installed by pip but no compilation dependencies. Thank you for the confirmation

Comment: ***"limitation .. provided to me"***: OK, what about your inital question, solved?

Comment: @stovfl - You were right, the process pid that I was trying to measure got killed for some reason. Which shouldn't have happened. Thanks!